# Does 'clearInterval' execute the function/Id that was passed in before clearing?

Tags: javascript, mobx

I have a working piece of code but I don't understand how its working. My objectives are...

- Trigger a function which increments a number by 10 every .25 seconds (`startLoadingProgress`)
- If this runs for 5 seconds, cancel the interval
- Have the ability to manually cancel the interval before 5 seconds if desired (`finishLoadingProgress`)

This is what I have come up with. Note I'm using MobX but this shouldn't affect the readability of what I'm trying to do...

```
intervalId: number = 0;

timer(): any {
    return setInterval(() => {
        runInAction(() => {
            this.loadingProgress += 10;
        });
    }, 250);
}

@action startLoadingProgress = () => {
    this.intervalId = this.timer();

    setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }, 5000);
};

@action finishLoadingProgress = () => {
    this.loadingProgress = 100;
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);       
};
```

I don't understand why `clearInterval(this.intervalId);` triggers my `timer()` function. I'm assigning an id with `this.intervalId = this.timer();` but why does the function referenced by this id trigger when passed into `clearInterval`? (I've checked this with `console.log` statements)

Comment: `clearInterval()` does not trigger the timer callback.

Comment: Not directly related, but you might want to adjust your numbers a bit. 5000 / 250 = 20 and 100 / 20 = 5

Comment: Your description is not very clear... How can you tell that clearInterval calls your function? This function is obviously called by `timer()` method, after 250ms

Comment: How are you calling all this code? The problem is probably in the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect something is calling `startLoadingProgress()` multiple times. The second call will start a new timer and replace `this.intervalId` with this, but the first timer continues to run. You should cancel the previous timer whenever starting a new one.

```
@action startLoadingProgress = () => {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    this.intervalId = this.timer();

    setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }, 5000);
};
```

You might also want to reset `this.loadingProgress` to `0` as well.